# Only INSERT INTO if not exist

Tags: php, mysql

I need to `INSERT INTO` if a value does not exist in a database and echo "ok". If the value does exist in the database, do not insert and echo "not ok".

This is my simple code;

```
<html>
<body>
    <?php
    $con = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die("Could not connect to host.");
    mysql_set_charset('UTF8',$con);
    if (!$con) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    $url= $_POST[url];
    $ok = "ok";
    $notok = " Not ok";

    mysql_select_db($database, $con) or die("Could not find database.");
    $sql="INSERT INTO link (url) VALUES ('$url' )";
    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)) {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo $ok."<br>";    

    mysql_close($con)
 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

The url comes from a textarea of a form.

Comment: I need to translate this first in propper english, ok? or not ok? :) I could tell you already, that since you use `mysql` functions, they are depricated, so suggesting you switch to `mysqli` or `pdo`

Comment: You mean first of all you want to check that value exist in db or not if exist then skip(Don't insert into db) else insert url into database. right?

Comment: ok or not ok is just for exa. how can i find if value already exit or not?

Comment: @Miya \ yes thats right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$con = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die("Could not connect to host.");
mysql_set_charset('UTF8',$con);
if (!$con)
{
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$url= $_POST[url];
$ok = "ok";
$notok = " Not ok";

mysql_select_db($database, $con) or die("Could not find database.");

///select url if already exist.
$q = "select url from link where url = '".$url."' ";
$mq = mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());
$mc = mysql_num_rows($mq);

//if mysql_num_rows return zero that means url is not exists in table and insert into table otherwise ignore it.

if($mc == 0)
{ 

    $sql="INSERT INTO link (url) VALUES ('$url' )";
    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    echo ok."<br>";
 }
 else
 {
      echo "Not Ok";
 }

 mysql_close($con)
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use query with mysqli :

Select count(*) from TABLE_NAME 
where URL=$url

And get the value in variable and check if the value is zero or not.

```
IF(count is greater than 0)

{

     //do insertion

}

else

{
     //exit
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the $url value already exists in your table using the select statment before executing the insert statement.

1. get the count of the value returned
2. if it is equal 0 ,you can perform insert else not

Answer (score -1):

Well for starters you're missing a `$` sign before `ok` on line 25, and there should be quotation marks around `url` in `$_POST[url]` on line 11. Also, be sure to use `mysqli` instead of `mysql`, more about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Answer (score -1):

You need to first check if URL is available in DB or not. You can use following query for the same.

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE url =  $url
```

Check if Count  = 0 then

```
<pre>$sql="INSERT INTO link (url) VALUES ('$url' )";
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo $ok."<br>";
```

else

```
echo $notok
```

Hope this helps!!!

Nishit